# Push content to hidden input from div after click on div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a question. I have for example 3 divs, all these dives should be clickable. And after click on div, value from div should be pushed to hidden input and form should be submitted automatically. How I can do it in a best way?

upd

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" class="hidden" id="inputID"/>
  <div id="placeholder">
    <div class="addresses">
        <div class="address">address 1</div>
        <div class="address">address 2</div>
        <div class="address">address 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

So, when you click to *.address*, value from *.address* should be pushed to *#inputID*

Comment: Can you show us some code?

Comment: @CláudioBarreira something like this

Comment: How about showing the jQuery code that you have tried? Where are the hidden inputs and form? The code would not be too hard if you show the details.

Comment: Is accessibility important in the app your are developing ?

Comment: @SamTyson that's a reason why I asked, because I have absolutelly no idea how it should be right now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following JavaScript should do what you are asking.

```js
$(".address").click(function() {
  $("#inputID").val($(this).text());
  $("form").submit();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" class="hidden" id="inputID"/>
  <div id="placeholder">
    <div class="addresses">
        <div class="address">address 1</div>
        <div class="address">address 2</div>
        <div class="address">address 3</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$('.address').on('click', function() {
   $('#inputID').val($(this).text());
   $('form').submit();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

`$('div.address').click(function() {
  $('#inputID').val($(this).text());
  $('form').submit();
});`

Comment: You also need to add an action for the form, or it won't accomplish anything.

Answer (score 1):

please look at this solution using jQuery:

HTML:

```
<form action="" method="get">
  <input type="text" class="hidden" id="inputID"/>
  <div id="placeholder">
    <div class="addresses">
        <div class="address">Berlin Leipzigerstr. 13</div>
        <div class="address">Berlin Firedrichstr. 2</div>
        <div class="address">Berlin Berlinerstr. 90</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

JavaScript:

```
$('.address').click(function(){
    $('#inputID').val($(this).text());
    $('form').submit();
});
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/AgilePlayers/Lgej9uz2/1/)